# How to simplify this code using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have next code:

```
let doNavigate = this.currentScreen === removedFqn;

if (doNavigate) { location.reload(); }
```

How can I simplify it using Typescript?

Comment: `if ( this.currentScreen === removedFqn) { location.reload(); }`

Comment: OR: `let doNavigate = this.currentScreen === removedFqn ? location.reload() : null;`

Answer (score 1):

```
(this.currentScreen === removedFqn) ? location.reload() : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though ternary operator is more simpler but its not readable. You can see how ugly it can look when it is not properly indented like I did here.

```
 this.currentScreen === removedFqn?location.reload():null;
```

Better to use `if` since the performance difference is almost negligible.

```
if(this.currentScreen === removedFqn){
      location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just do this

```
if (this.currentScreen === removedFqn) { location.reload(); }
```

but that has nothing to do with TypeScript